# Rails check partial is fully loaded following ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I render a partial after an ajax call:

**show.js.erb**

```
$("#notice_feed").html("<%=j render 'shared/notice_feed' %>")
```

**_notice_feed.html.erb**

```
<ol class="notices" id="notice_list">
  <%= render @notices %>
</ol>
```

This ends up rendering a list of `@notices`. The names of each notice are listed on the right and I have some jquery to scroll down to the relevant rendered `@notice` when you click on the name:

```
name.on('click', function() {
  $("#absolute-div").animate({scrollTop: $('#notice_' + this.className).offset().top -200 }, 500); 
});
```

When you click on the name it correctly scrolls down, but only sometimes stops scrolling on the correct `@notice`, and gets nowhere near for other `@notices`. I suspect the problem is that the jquery is called before the whole partial list has finished rendering. I've tried surrounding the javascript with

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  ...
};
```

but this doesn't fire, presumably because it already fired when the original page was loaded.

How do I check that a partial following an ajax call has fully loaded using jquery?

Or is there a better way to identify a div and scroll to it accurately?

Comment: It's easy to [check if an element exists with jquery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/) so maybe you want to use that as a gate to allowing the click?  The current check you are using can't tell if there are more partials to load.

Comment: Maybe you can try with `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});` instead of  `$(window).on("load", function() {
  ...
};`

Comment: "I render a partial after an ajax call:" Is this in a callback or inline? If its in a callback, then place your other code in the same callback. If its not then it should be.

Comment: The ajax hits the `show` action of the controller, which then calls `show.js.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

**Rails way:**

Make a method on js for call the animate scroll something like that:

```
name.on('click', function() {
  scrolling_to(this.className);
});
function scrollin_to(name){
  $("#absolute-div").animate({scrollTop: $('#notice_' + name).offset().top -200 }, 500); 
}
```

Then, in show.js.erb do that:

```
 scrolling_to(@notice_show.name);
```

**Js way:**

Use ajax to call to the rails route:

```
jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'get',    
          url: 'your url here',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data, textStatus){
            $("#notice_feed").html(data.msg);
            $("#absolute-div").animate({scrollTop: $('#notice_' + data.name).offset().top -200 }, 500);
          }
        });
```

Rails show method:

```
def show
  data ={
   msg: @notice_feed
   name: @notice_feed.name
  }
render json: data;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I changed `.offset()` to `.position()`. Now it works beautifully.

```
name.on('click', function() {
  $("#absolute-div").animate({scrollTop: $('#notice_' + this.className).position().top -200 }, 500); 
});
```

I needed the position of the `@notices` relative to the parent, not the document (jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)).